# Xcode 7.3.1 Working with iAd Bannerviews Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After following countless tutorials and trying different methods, my iAd banners simply do not show while running the simulation, and if they do, they fade quickly without displaying anything.

This is the current code I am using to display an iAd banner:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations]; }

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations]; }
```

I have delegated the banner to the view, have imported the iAd framework in the viewcontroller.h, and followed all other necessary steps. However, while launching the simulator (in any phone size) an ad does not appear, even after waiting a considerable amount of time. I have no errors or other indications that I have done something wrong, and have been stuck on this for a while. Why won't the banner show?

Comment: Have tried setting a breakpoint in `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` to see if that gets called? That would make the banner disappear.

Comment: I tried switching the Alpha in the     `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` and the white box of the banner appears now. Does this mean the iAd banner will actually work, but just has no ad to display at this time?

Comment: That's why I'm saying you should set a breakpoint there to see if that's what's happening. When you hit the breakpoint, you can type `po error` or `po [error localizedDescription]` to get more details on the error.

Comment: I believe I did this right, but this is the message I got: `Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=4 "Application has iAd Network configuration error" UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=4, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application has iAd Network configuration error, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}`